# ¿Por que mi "page web not found 404" en laravel 5.3 no me sirve?

Tags: laravel-5

creo una vista y la agrego al archivo `app/Exception/Handler.php` de la sigueinte manera:

```
public function render($request, Exception $e){
    if ($this->isHttpException($e)){
        return $this->renderHttpException($e);
    }else if($e instanceof NotFoundHttpException){
        return response()->view('errors.404', [], 404);
    }else{
        return parent::render($request, $e);
    }
}
```

la Vista:

```html
@extends('layouts.plantilla_general') 
 
@section('content')
        <div id="page-wrapper">
            <div class="row"> 
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <h1 class="page-header">Error</h1>
                </div>
                <!-- /.col-lg-12 -->
            </div>
            <!-- /.row -->
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12 col-center">
                    <div class="panel panel-default">
                        <div class="panel-heading">
                            Error
                        </div>
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <h1>Error 404</h1>
                            <h3>La dirección que usted indicó no se encuentra.</h3>
                            <h3>Por favor, verifique e intente de nuevo.</h3>
                        </div>
                        <div class="panel-footer">

                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- /.panel -->

                </div>
                <!-- /.col-lg-12 -->
            </div>
            <!-- /.row -->
        </div>
        <!-- /#page-wrapper -->
@stop
```

Esa plantilla que uso me funciona correctamente en todos los demás vistas y la llamo de la manera.

En esa vista no me funciona o desconozco el por que del sigueinte error:

> 3/3
> ErrorException in f01ad76b252031da132b58646a0076e33be5b20b.php line 239:
> Trying to get property of non-object (View: D:\Mis Documentos\Pablo\SIMante\Sistema\SIMante\resources\views\layouts\plantilla_general.blade.php) (View: D:\Mis Documentos\Pablo\SIMante\Sistema\SIMante\resources\views\layouts\plantilla_general.blade.php)

> 2/3
> ErrorException in f01ad76b252031da132b58646a0076e33be5b20b.php line 239:
> Trying to get property of non-object (View: D:\Mis Documentos\Pablo\SIMante\Sistema\SIMante\resources\views\layouts\plantilla_general.blade.php)

> 1/3
> ErrorException in f01ad76b252031da132b58646a0076e33be5b20b.php line 239:
> Trying to get property of non-object

Answer (score 1):

Pablo, el error dice que el problema está en la plantilla general (línea 239), puede que al estar en una página incorrecta no estas cargando algún objeto (de ahí el error Trying to get property of non-object - Intentando acceder a una propiedad de un No-objeto).

Revisa esa línea y verás que objeto estás consultando, lo más probable que sea del usuario autenticado o algo así.

Saludos.

PD: cuando laravel te tira estos errores es más fácil ir a la vista compilada y ver a que línea se refiere, en este caso el archivo se llama **f01ad76b252031da132b58646a0076e33be5b20b.php** y está en el directorio **storage/framework/views**.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, aunque no esta muy clara tu respuesta, estas en lo cierto es el usuario autenticado, pero el usuario esta autenticado correctamente ¿Por que en el error lanza ese error? cual es la solución.

Comment: la autenticacion la uso para capturar el id del perfil y el nombre del usuario logueado. El id del perfil lo uso para crear el menu dinamico y el nombre para que el usuario vea quien esta logueado.

Comment: En laravel 5.3 no se puede consultar el usuario en las paginas de error, incluida la pagina de 404. https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/13517

Answer (score 0):

Como comenta José Eduardo Rios, debes revisar plantilla_general.blade.php ya que seguramente estás intentando obtener un atributo que no existe en un objeto.